# Smooth functions with linearly independent gradients extend to coordinate charts (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds

This feels obvious, but I can't find a reference for it. Suppose I have a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, and I have $k$ smooth functions $f_1,\ldots,f_k \in C^\infty(M)$ such at some point $x \in M$, the gradients $\nabla f_1,\ldots,\nabla f_k$ are linearly independent at $x$ (and therefore in a neighbourhood of $x$). Can I find $n-k$ functions $f_{k+1},\ldots,f_n \in C^\infty(M)$ and a set $U \subset M$ containing $x$ such that $(U,(f_1,\ldots,f_n))$ forms a smooth coordinate chart for $M$ (i.e. is contained in the maximal atlas for $M$)?

Comment: In other words, you have a map $F: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, whose Jacobian has maximal rank at $x$, i.e., the map is a submersion near $x$. Now look up the canonical submersion theorem.

Comment: Thank you - that's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Deane points out in the comments, this is an application of the *canonical submersion theorem*. It appears in e.g. Guillemin and Haine's *Differential Forms*, Theorem 4.2.14.